# How to get return type of a function

Tags: go, reflection

I'm writing higher order functions in Go, and am trying to figure out the return type of the inner function `f`.

As a simple example, let's say I want to return the default value of the return type of the inner function:

- if `f` returns string, `GetDefault(f)` returns `""`
- if `f` returns []byte, `GetDefault(f)` return `[]byte{}`

```golang
func GetDefault(func(interface{})) {
  // How would I write this function?
}
```

Is it possible to write such a function in Go, **without running `f`**?

Comment: Neither of your function signatures return anything. You could make them both return `interface{}` in which case you don't need to change anything, since you can return the same `interface{}` value or something derived from it. You cannot change the actual type signature, nor are there covariant result types: see the [FAQ](https://golang.org/doc/faq#covariant_types)

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/BhevFvsut5z

Comment: Bear in mind that **Go allows functions to have multiple return values**.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks, that helped. If you're willing to make an answer, I'll tick it green.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use reflection to get the type and initialize a default value.

```
func GetDefault(f interface{}) interface{} {
    ft := reflect.TypeOf(f)
    if ft.Kind() != reflect.Func {
        panic("not a func")
    }

    out0 := ft.Out(0) // type of the 0th output value
    return reflect.New(out0).Elem().Interface()
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BhevFvsut5z